# Error when trying to call RScript from Python using subprocess

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to run an R script within a Python script by using `subprocess.call`, but I'm getting an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Rscript'`

For reference the code I'm trying to run is `subprocess.call(['Rscript', 'createTree.R', str(n_leaves), file])`, where the last two arguments are args for the R script.

I'm running this in a Conda environment, is this a possible reason why I'm getting this issue? I'm on Python 3.9.

Comment: Where is `Rscript` located? What is your [`PATH`](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html)? This seems a case of you not knowing or specifying where the executable is located. (You can either update your `PATH` env var to include the directory of the `Rscript` executable, or specify the full path, as in `subprocess.call(['/path/to/Rscript', ...])`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @r2evans my `PATH` contains `/usr/bin/` which I can see contains `Rscript`. I can run `Rscript` normally from the shell as well (and also with my Conda environment activated), it's just Python doesn't seem to work

Comment: You're saying that `subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/Rscript',...)` gives the same error?